# Remove matching values from two columns and shift remaining values up

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a very large list of time clock records with matching OUT/IN punches that need to be removed. I would like an array formula that will spill out the results without any other editing other than copy/paste of the data.

Ultimately, all punches for an individual employee should be unique and only appear once. Any OUT/IN punches that match should be removed, and the remaining values shifted up with no blank cells remaining.

Here's what the punches look like before any adjustment (starting in A1):

| ID | Date | IN | OUT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123SAM | 9/10/23 | 9/11/23 4:28 | 9/11/23 7:57 |
| 123SAM | 9/11/23 | 9/11/23 15:29 | 9/11/23 19:38 |
| 543AND | 9/16/23 | 9/16/23 23:22 | 9/17/23 0:00 |
| 543AND | 9/16/23 | 9/17/23 0:00 | 9/17/23 3:11 |
| 543AND | 9/16/23 | 9/17/23 3:42 | 9/17/23 8:13 |

Here's what it should look like after the adjustment (starting in F1):

| ID | Date | IN | OUT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123SAM | 9/10/23 | 9/11/23 4:28 | 9/11/23 7:57 |
| 123SAM | 9/11/23 | 9/11/23 15:29 | 9/11/23 19:38 |
| 543AND | 9/16/23 | 9/16/23 23:22 | 9/17/23 3:11 |
| 543AND | 9/16/23 | 9/17/23 3:42 | 9/17/23 8:13 |

So far my closest attempt at this is to essentially use a helper column with ID&Punch-IN and try to find a match with ID&Punch-OUT and return a blank cell. It doesn't work. I need an array formula that will remove any matches plus shift values up and ignore the unnecessary row at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for me, you could try as well,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,A2:A6&"|"&C2:C6,
     b,A2:A6&"|"&D2:D6,
     HSTACK(FILTER(A2:C6,ISNA(XMATCH(a,b))),FILTER(D2:D6,ISNA(XMATCH(b,a)))))
```

---

Update:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F9</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _lRow,MATCH(2,1/(A:A<>"")),
     _a,A2:INDEX(A:A,_lRow),
     _c,C2:INDEX(C:C,_lRow),
     _d,D2:INDEX(D:D,_lRow),
     _b,B2:INDEX(B:B,_lRow),
     _ac,_a&"|"&_c,
     _ad,_a&"|"&_d,
     HSTACK(
     FILTER(HSTACK(_a,_b,_c),ISNA(XMATCH(_ac,_ad))),
     FILTER(_d,ISNA(XMATCH(_ad,_ac)))))
```

---

Comment: Thanks! Although it looks like this works when the ranges are explicitly defined, the copy and paste of data doesn't always have the same range. Therefore, anyone using the tool would have to edit the ranges in the formula. Trying to avoid editing the formula. I have trouble when I try to make the range dynamic using something like `A2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A))&" | "&C2:INDEX(C:C,COUNTA(C:C))`. It works for `a` but a similar approach doesn't also work for b. Then I need it to also work in the `HSTACK` line as well.

Comment: @Ramon I havent got any problem, please refer the answer, also you need to use anyone of the column as a base to get the last row.